# How to filter with NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, filter, stream, npoi

So I'd like to filter a range of cells in Excel using NPOI. However I get a strange error, when using the "SetAutoFilter" method:

Code:

```
IAutoFilter filter = sh.SetAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,2));
```

Error:" Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream') "